# How to include (x86) in a regex query

Tags: regex

I am trying to include `(x86)` in a keyword search that is derived from `C:\Program Files (x86)`. Is there a way to escape the `()` in the keyword search so that it is included with the x86?

Answer (score -2):

I think what you are searching for is "\(x86\)". This should work with almost every regex engine/compiler.